# creating a dropdown list module in joomla

Tags: joomla

I am new to joomla and doing a project in joomla for the very first time so i need help from you. I want a drop down list in which there will be districts of my country Nepal, and when anybody selects any district then the description of that district will be displayed in the bottom of the drop down list. And I am confused that where can I get such module or if I have to make such module then how can I do it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck. This module does exactly what you need. The code is not packaged for distrbution yet, but you can register for the site and request a copy of the code -

http://bgies.com/index.php/joomla-extensions/7-joomla-country-state-extension.html